# Is it possible to move Files outside localhost with PHP?

Tags: php, file, directory, zip, structure

i realize for each client in my business i have same folder/files structure, so i've made a folder/files template and instead of creating all folders/files my own, using a PHP script running on my localhost i copy that template and duplicate the folders/files on a folder named after the client, here the code:

```
$clientName = "RosaBazbaz";
$tmpPath = __DIR__ . "/tmp";
$templatesPath = __DIR__ . "/templates";
$absoluteZIPPath = join("/", [$tmpPath, $clientName]) . ".zip";

//Creates ZIP file containing all folder/files structure in template
$zip = new ZipArchive();

if($zip->open($absoluteZIPPath,  ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE | ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)) {

$source = realpath(join("/", [$templatesPath, "lunasMiel"]));

if(is_dir($source)) {

    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($source, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

    foreach($files as $file) {

        $file = realpath($file);

        if(is_dir($file)) {

            $zip->addEmptyDir(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file . '/'));

        } else if(is_file($file)) {

            $zip->addFromString(str_replace($source . '/', '', $file), file_get_contents($file));
        }
    }

} else if(is_file($source)) {

    $zip->addFromString(basename($source), file_get_contents($source));
}
}

$zip->close();

//Extracts Generated ZIP
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open($absoluteZIPPath) != "true") {

    echo "Error :- Unable to open the Zip File";
}

$zip->extractTo(str_replace(".zip", "", $absoluteZIPPath));
$zip->close();

//Deletes Zip File
unlink($absoluteZIPPath);
```

My question is: I need to have those folders in my Google Drive so i have them backed up and shared with coworkers, so is it possible somehow to make the script move them outside my localhost?

Comment: Yes, as long as the user that runs php/apache has sufficiant rights to write there it should be no problem.

Comment: Might be a problem if, say,  `open_basedir` is set to the document root.

Comment: that was it @cHao thx!